# Transformers - LLAMA2 13B - Key Error / Attribute Error

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, large-language-model, llama

I'm trying to load and run the LLAMA2 13B model on my local machine, however I'm not able test any prompts due to an Key Error / Attribute Error (see image attached).

[image]

My machine has the following specs:

- CPU: AMD® Ryzen threadripper 3960x 24-core processor × 48
- Memory: 128GB
- GPU: Nvidia Titan RTX

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!
Cheers

Comment: Could you please share your code instead of an image please?

Answer (score 1):

Found the error myself. Referencing my source here:
https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/12503

Input has to be a tensor and not a BatchEncoding.

You can solve this by using:

`input.input_ids`

or

`kwargs` as `**input`

So the solution looks like this:

```py
outputs = model.generate(**inputs, max_new_tokens=20)
```